# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Code seems to be correct

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench, mamp

I can't connect with database using Sequelize, code seems to be correct.  MAMP server is running and connected to mySQL workbench. There is created farmerdb. mysql2 is installed and listed in package.json. But still I get this error message.

> SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> at ConnectionManager.connect (/Users/jav/farmerAPI/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:118:17)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> name: 'SequelizeAccessDeniedError',
> parent:
> { Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> at Packet.asError (/Users/jav/farmerAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
> at ClientHandshake.execute (/Users/jav/farmerAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
> at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/jav/farmerAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
> at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (/Users/jav/farmerAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB_NAME, dbConfig.DB_USER, dbConfig.DB_PASSWORD,{
    host: dbConfig.DB_HOST,
    dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
    port: dbConfig.PORT,
    logging: false
});
```

```
module.exports = {
    DB_HOST: 'localhost',
    DB_USER: 'root',
    DB_PASSWORD: '12345678',
    DB_NAME: 'farmerdb',
    dialect : 'mysql',
    PORT: 3306   
}
```

```
// DB
const db = require('./models/index')
async ()=> {
    try{
        await db.sync()
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

MAMP server running
[image]

MySQLWorkbench connected to MAMP server. Successfully Host 127.0.0.1 Port 3306 User root.

Comment: Your password is correct? `root` can access to `farmerdb`?

Comment: Yes, that was! Now I'm stabilized connection. But Im not seen tables anywhere!